# Why it is slower to get query result from z3 java API then get from z3 directly?

Tags: java, z3, smt

Just noticed that for some benchmarks, it is really slow to get query result from z3 via java API. However, if I just dumped the query into smt2 format, and run z3 in the command line directly, it takes less than a second. Wonder why?

Comment: This problem is likely due to different options or tactics being used (also note that in debug configuration Z3 is slower and uses different tactics). Do you have a (small) example so I can see what options are being used and which tactics are called?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger, just checked, no special option has been set via Z3 java API. I do have a example (not small enough to be paste here) on my google drive [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_Ha24MKXu0JsDE5Z_XGOQ1uRLfxKF1rNFeNH_jim-9g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you also have the corresponding problem from the Java API? Perhaps a logfile (via Log.open) would be the best way to share that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your problem contains a `(push)` command, removing this changes the performance dramatically. When Z3 first sees a `(push)`, it switches to a different solver that supports incrementality and that can have a dramatic impact on the performance. By setting the verbosity to 15 via -v:15, the first line of Z3s output tells you which solver it is using, e.g., when the `push` command is present it says

```
(combined-solver "using solver 2 (without a timeout)")
```

and when it is not, then it says

```
(combined-solver "using solver 1")
```

For the given example, solver 2 happens to be significantly faster.